# How to fetch list of all fields in a table in Salesforce?

Tags: sql, salesforce, soql

Is there a way to fetch a list of all fields in a table in Salesforce?

Below is SQL statement which I am using to get all the column from that particular table:

```
SELECT * FROM myTableName;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get all fields.
Only via additional SOAP API.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL : 
  Execute query **describe myTableName;**

MS SQL :
  Execute query **exec sp_columns MyTable**

Answer (score 0):

select t.name,c.name from sys.tables t join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id

It will display all the fields of all the tables in your DB

OR 
select t.name,c.name from sys.tables t join sys.columns c on t.object_id=c.object_id where t.name like '%TableName%' will display all the fields of a particular table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need that for Account object (for the reference), try this:

```
String[] allFields = new String[]{};
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fields = Schema.Account.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
for (String fieldName:fields.keySet()) {
    DescribeFieldResult fieldDesc = fields.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
    if (fieldDesc.isAccessible()) {
        allFields.add(fieldDesc.getName());
    }
}
Account[] accs = Database.query('select ' + String.join(allFields, ', ') + ' from Account limit 1');
system.debug(accs);
```

Comment: my question is, i have one table like 'myTable' and i want to execute and get the all column and value by SOQL with below query: select * from myTable; so is this possible by salesforce sql or not?

Comment: No you can't use wildcards ( like '*' ) in field lists in SOQL. That is you MUST explicitly determine the fields you want to select.